# MySQL - phpmyadmin import one csv and insert data to two tables

Tags: mysql, csv, import, phpmyadmin

I have a database, for example test, with two tables `table1:general, table2:credentials`.
In table1 I have 2 fields `name, surname` and in table2 I have two fields `username, password`
I have one csv file that has 4 columns `name, surname, username, password`.

Can I import that file `(PHPMyadmin)` and insert the data to both tables at once?
Thank you

Comment: If these values are connected to one person - why do you need to split this data into two different tables?

Comment: No you can't import into two tables at once.

Comment: The mentioned values was an example. I believe that Lex is right....